# Error ocurred during deployment JSF-Spring app

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, glassfish-3

hi I am using eclipse indigo and glassfish 3.1.2 and i am getting this exception while deploying my web app. I have added latest spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar to my build path also, but problem still there: here is the exception

```
cannot Deploy jsfspring
Deployment Error for module: jsfspring: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener. Please see server.log for more details.
```

this is exception details:

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5332)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2018)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addApplicationListener(StandardContext.java:1966)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureApplicationListener(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureWebModule(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.start(WebModuleContextConfig.java:274)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(WebModuleContextConfig.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5329)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadListener(StandardContext.java:4806)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.loadListener(WebModule.java:1599)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2740)
    ... 46 more

WARNING: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2018)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE: Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your glassfish running the same java version as your project?  I had this problem when running glassfish on 1.6 but my project used 1.7.  Check your java environment variables.  Restart glassfish using the java version your project needs.

Comment: Didn't help in my case

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in one of the [answers](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?60812-ClassNotFoundException-org-springframework-web-con-text-ContextLoaderListener/page2), and [posts](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?60812-ClassNotFoundException-org-springframework-web-con-text-ContextLoaderListener&p=379143#post379143):

> For what it's worth, running a spring app from within eclipse can be a
>   very frustrating experience, especially when insisting on the latest
>   and greatest + maven. I found that the Maven dependencies are not
>   included in WEB-INF/lib unless the project is configured as shown in
>   the attached screenie. May it save you precious development time!
>   Happy Hacking!!! !

To add in [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/):
Go to **Project Properties** > **Deployment Assembly** > **Add** > **Java Build Path Entries** 
Select **Maven Dependencies**

[image: Eclipse Deployment Assembly]

Answer (score 1):

I use netbeans 7.3 + glassfish 3.1.2.2 + spring 3.2.2 + maven.
In process of upgrading my project to spring 3.2.2 there was similar error "...java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild.. blah-blah"
Historically my local .m2 folder is dirty of old spring 3.0.7, 3.1.1 and etc.

After some upgrades my project.war:WEB-INF/lib became full of spring 3.0.7, 3.1.1, 3.2.2 copies.

Solution in may case is:

1. ensure that all dependencies have appropriate versions (spring 3.2.2
   based)
2. clean maven /.m2 (at least
   repository/org/springframework)
3. clean project or remove target build
   folder.

look at project.war:WEB-INF/lib - in my war all spring libraries are 3.2.2-versioned and glassfish deployment is Ok.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your libraries are not deployed to the server. Check inside `glassfish` if the libraries are deployed properly.

Look [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?60812-ClassNotFoundException-org-springframework-web-con-text-ContextLoaderListener) also.

Answer (score 0):

Just for people that might be running into this exception as well, this could be caused as well by a web service method that returns a type not supported by JAX-WS. In my case I had a method that returned HashMap, which is not supported by JAX-WS.

"JAX-WS delegates the mapping of Java programming language types to and from XML definitions to JAXB. Application developers don’t need to know the details of these mappings but should be aware that not every class in the Java language can be used as a method parameter or return type in JAX-WS."

next we have a list of **Schema-to-Java mappings**:

```
**XML Schema Type** **Java Data Type**

    xsd:string  java.lang.String
    xsd:integer java.math.BigInteger
    xsd:int int
    xsd.long    long
    xsd:short   short
    xsd:decimal java.math.BigDecimal
    xsd:float   float
    xsd:double  double
    xsd:boolean boolean
    xsd:byte    byte
    xsd:QName   javax.xml.namespace.QName
    xsd:dateTime    javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar
    xsd:base64Binary    byte[]
    xsd:hexBinary   byte[]
    xsd:unsignedInt long
    xsd:unsignedShort   int
    xsd:unsignedByte    short
    xsd:time    javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar
    xsd:date    javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar
    xsd:g   javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar
    xsd:anySimpleType   java.lang.Object
    xsd:anySimpleType   java.lang.String
    xsd:duration    javax.xml.datatype.Duration
    xsd:NOTATION    javax.xml.namespace.QName
```

and **Java-to-Schema mappings**:

```
Java Class  XML Data Type
java.lang.String    xs:string
java.math.BigInteger    xs:integer
java.math.BigDecimal    xs:decimal
java.util.Calendar  xs:dateTime
java.util.Date  xs:dateTime
javax.xml.namespace.QName   xs:QName
java.net.URI    xs:string
javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar xs:anySimpleType
javax.xml.datatype.Duration xs:duration
java.lang.Object    xs:anyType
java.awt.Image  xs:base64Binary
javax.activation.DataHandler    xs:base64Binary
javax.xml.transform.Source  xs:base64Binary
java.util.UUID  xs:string
```

if the return value on your web method is not listed above, you have to find a work around.